# Selecting an int and dividing using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How do I select an int, then divide it by 100 using MYSQL?

Comment: Is this int a variable? Is it a column in a table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select (field / 100) as divided
  From Table;
```

Comment: I can honestly say I didn't expect that to be so easy!

Answer (score 2):

Simple divide. The question is, do you want integer arithmetic?

For example, 163 / 100 = 1. So you need to convert it implicitly or explicitly first to get 1.63

```
SELECT MyColumn * 1.0 / 100 FROM MyTable
```

or

```
SELECT MyColumn / 100.0 FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this sql query:

```
SELECT 16800 /* = an int */ / 100
```